# why the object $result have been changed

Tags: php, object

I have some codes like blow,

```
class Tool{
    function getData(){
        $res = array('name'=>'jay','age'=>22,'job'=>'developer','ID'=>1233211234567);
        $res = (object)$res;
        var_dump(111,$res);
        $resLog = $res;
        $this->resFilter($resLog);
        var_dump(222,$res);
        //...log code
    }
    function resFilter($res){
        unset($res->ID);
    }
}
echo '<pre>';
$t = new Tool;
$t->getData();
die;
```

and I doubt why after call function `resFilter` in function `getData` the `var_dump(222,$res);` will be this :

```
int(111)
object(stdClass)#2 (4) {
  ["name"]=>
  string(3) "jay"
  ["age"]=>
  int(22)
  ["job"]=>
  string(9) "developer"
  ["ID"]=>
  int(1233211234567)
}
int(222)
object(stdClass)#2 (3) {
  ["name"]=>
  string(3) "jay"
  ["age"]=>
  int(22)
  ["job"]=>
  string(9) "developer"
}
```

so you can see in second part of var_dump have no `ID` field? Who can help me , and tell me why?

update:
 thanks for your answer, and I try this `$resLog = clone($res);` will work fine.

Comment: You cast your `$res` variable in into object

Comment: I know the point you say , but I do not know why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best explanation is here, also with an example like yours :

http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.references.php

Long story short : When you apply the resFilter method you send the `$resLog` object as input and that object has the same identifier like `$res` because you made the `$resLog = $res;` It is rather the same thing if you had a normal variable but sent it with reference in a method.

> When an object is sent by argument, returned or assigned to another
>   variable, the different variables are not aliases: they hold a copy of
>   the identifier, **which points to the same object**.

Answer (score 1):

PHP implements shallow copies unless instructed otherwise. So when you copy the object you do not actually clone it completely, you work with a reference instead. Therefore the `$this->resFilter($resLog);` call will delete the `ID` propety in the referenced object too.